# Visual Studio Solution not displaying and automatically closing when open when using third party toolbox controls

Tags: vb.net, winforms, formclosing

Whenever I try to add custom toolbox controls to my Windows Form app, the application will not display when open and will automatically close. When the control is deleted it works properly.

I've tried to make another projects and test to see if the results were the same, and it is. It initially starts by working but then it stops.
What's weird is that when debug in Visual Studio it opens properly but not when building the app.

This happens with any Winform third party control

Please help.

I've tried to make another projects and test to see if the results were the same, and it is. It initially starts by working but then it stops.
What's weird is that when debug in Visual Studio it opens properly but not when building the app.

Comment: Most likely this is something specific to your system but I would suggest that you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. At least then we can confirm that we're not seeing the same behaviour under the same circumstances or possibly identify an issue with what you're doing. It may be that a repair of VS is the best next step.

Comment: I've found out the issue, it was missing DLL's from the installed third party packages. After updating VS and building the solution again, it created the DLL's.

Comment: Ensure that both your project and the UserControl have the same bitness. If the UserControl is 32-bit, set your project to 32-bit. If the UserControl is 64-bit, set your project to 64-bit.